# Python check if string contains dictionary key

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, find

I have these strings:

```
>>> a="foo"
>>> b="foo_KEY"
```

And a dictionary like:

```
>>> DICT
{
'KEY': ['...'],
'KEY2': ['...', '...'],
...
}
```

I'd like to build a function that check if the test value is in any key of the input dict:

```
>>> has_key(a, DICT)
False
>>> has_key(b, DICT)
True
```

What is the most elegant way to do this task in Python 3?

Comment: Are you asking to see if the test value is in any key in the dict?

Comment: @muddyfish Exactly. I edit my question to make it clearer

Comment: You ask *I'd like to build a function that check if the test value is in any key of the input dict*, that is not what your output shows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
has_key = lambda a, d: any(k in a for k in d)
```

Comment: @AndyKubiak [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) are very powerful built-in functions, you gonna love them. ;)

Comment: Why is this a lambda?

Comment: There is no need to use .keys you can iterate over a dicts keys

Comment: There's no need to explicitly call `d.keys()`; iterating over a dict means to iterate over its keys.

Comment: @chepner & Padraic How could I miss this? Thank you.

Comment: It's not as big a deal in py3 but changes your code from an `O(1)` lookup to an `O(n)` lookup in python2